# Obligation not executed XACML Balana

Tags: xacml, xacml3, pdp, balana

I'm trying to run this simple PDP : I enter an XML as argument and print the response. 
The response is correct but i see no interpretation/execution of the obligation part. 
What am i doin wrong ?

Main :

```
    package run;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openliberty.openaz.azapi.AzEntity;
import org.openliberty.openaz.azapi.AzRequestContext;
import org.openliberty.openaz.azapi.AzResponseContext;
import org.openliberty.openaz.azapi.AzResult;
import org.openliberty.openaz.azapi.AzService;
import org.openliberty.openaz.azapi.constants.AzCategoryIdAction;
import org.openliberty.openaz.azapi.constants.AzCategoryIdResource;
import org.openliberty.openaz.azapi.constants.AzCategoryIdSubjectAccess;
import org.openliberty.openaz.azapi.constants.AzDataTypeIdString;
import org.openliberty.openaz.azapi.constants.AzXacmlStrings;
import org.wso2.balana.ParsingException;
import org.wso2.balana.UnknownIdentifierException;
import org.wso2.balana.openaz.provider.AzServiceFactory;
import org.wso2.balana.openaz.provider.SimpleConcreteBalanaService;

public class Main_ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SimpleConcreteBalanaService service = null;
        try {
            service = new SimpleConcreteBalanaService("policy_.xml", "PATHTODAPOLICY");
        } catch (ParsingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownIdentifierException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AzServiceFactory.registerDefaultProvider(service);
        AzService azHandle = AzServiceFactory.getAzService();

        AzRequestContext azReqCtx = azHandle.createAzRequestContext();

        AzEntity<AzCategoryIdSubjectAccess> accSubj = azReqCtx.createAzEntity(AzCategoryIdSubjectAccess.AZ_CATEGORY_ID_SUBJECT_ACCESS);
        accSubj.createAzAttribute("AuthNSystem",AzXacmlStrings.X_ATTR_SUBJECT_ID, accSubj.createAzAttributeValue(AzDataTypeIdString.AZ_DATATYPE_ID_STRING,"alice"));
        azReqCtx.addAzEntity(accSubj);

        AzEntity<AzCategoryIdResource> azResource = azReqCtx.createAzEntity(AzCategoryIdResource.AZ_CATEGORY_ID_RESOURCE);
        azResource.createAzAttribute("applicationName",AzXacmlStrings.X_ATTR_RESOURCE_ID,azResource.createAzAttributeValue(AzDataTypeIdString.AZ_DATATYPE_ID_STRING, "doc"));
        azReqCtx.addAzEntity(azResource);

        AzEntity<AzCategoryIdAction> azAction = azReqCtx.createAzEntity(AzCategoryIdAction.AZ_CATEGORY_ID_ACTION);
        azAction.createAzAttribute("applicationName",AzXacmlStrings.X_ATTR_ACTION_ID, azAction.createAzAttributeValue(AzDataTypeIdString.AZ_DATATYPE_ID_STRING,"read"));
        azReqCtx.addAzEntity(azAction);

        Set<AzEntity<AzCategoryIdAction>> azActions = new HashSet<AzEntity<AzCategoryIdAction>>();
        azActions.add(azAction);
        azReqCtx.addResourceActionAssociation(azResource, azActions);
        AzResponseContext azRspCtx = azHandle.decide(azReqCtx);
        AzResult azResult = null;

        Iterator<AzResult> itResults = azRspCtx.getResults().iterator();

        while (itResults.hasNext()) {
            azResult = itResults.next();
            System.out.println(azResult.getAzDecision() );
        }
    }

}
```

XML policy

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Policy
      xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17 http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-core-v3-schema-wd-17.xsd"
      PolicyId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:conformance-test:IIA1:policy"
      RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides"
      Version="3.0"
      >
    <Description>

    </Description>
    <Target/>
    <Rule
          RuleId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:conformance-test:IIA1:rule"
          Effect="Permit">
        <Description>
      test
        </Description>
       <Target>
    <AnyOf>
      <AllOf>
        <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
          <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
          <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"/>
        </Match>
      </AllOf>
      <AllOf>
        <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
          <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">access</AttributeValue>
          <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"/>
        </Match>
      </AllOf>
    </AnyOf>
    <AnyOf>
      <AllOf>
        <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
          <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">alice</AttributeValue>
          <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"/>
        </Match>
        <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
          <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">doc</AttributeValue>
          <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"/>
        </Match>
      </AllOf>
    </AnyOf>
  </Target>
     <ObligationExpressions>
    <ObligationExpression FulfillOn="Permit" ObligationId="email">
      <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="emailId" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" Issuer="">
        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="manager-email" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"/>
      </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
    </ObligationExpression>
  </ObligationExpressions>

    </Rule>

</Policy>
```

Result :

```
 ###########################################################################################
   Start processing request number: 1
     for AzResourceActionAssociation w correlationId = 0
        Subject  AzEntity.getId: AzEntity(AzCategoryIdSubjectAccess)-0
        Resource AzEntity.getId: AzEntity(AzCategoryIdResource)-1
        Action   AzEntity.getId: AzEntity(AzCategoryIdAction)-2
         requestor subject-id:  alice
         requested resource-id: doc
         requested action-id:   read
      All attributes: 
        Num subject attrs: 1
        Id: urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id
         Val: "alice"
        Num resource attrs: 1
        Id: urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id
         Val: "doc"
        Num action attrs: 1
        Id: urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id
         Val: "read"
      Using AzService w azServiceCounter = 1
###########################################################################################

======================== XACML Request ====================
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">access</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">alice</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">doc</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request>
===========================================================

======================== XACML Response ===================
<Response>
<Result>
<Decision>Permit</Decision>
<Status>
<StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
</Status>
</Result>
</Response>
```

Comment: Does Balana implement obligations? I notice you are using XACML 2.0 as well which has limited obligations. Switch to XACML 3.0 which the Axiomatics XACML engine supports.

Comment: I switched my policy to XACML 3.0 but nothing changed in the response :(

Comment: I corrected my XACML 3.0, this time it works thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what was wrong in the policy for future generations? Add a response to your own question